# Undefined symbols for architecture armv6, Updating to iOS 4.3

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios, ios4

I am patching upp an application from iOS 4.2 to 4.3 using new xcode4.
With no changes made, except setting iOS to 4.3, I created entitlements and go!

Message I get is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv6:"function", referenced from:
```

Ive tried to Clean the project, reinstalling xcode. 
I uninstalled also the xcode4 demo version.
I also tried to set to Optimized armv7.

I would be very happy for some help, I'm stuck. Really.

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Where was `function` referenced from? Does anything look funny in the referenced file?

Comment: Try adding the i386 under Valid Architecture under Targets and Project Build Settings

Comment: Please include the full text of the error.

Comment: Are you linking in any libraries? Has the library with the symbol "function" been compiled for armv6 architecture?

Comment: Is this an universal application? You might get this error when using some classes that only exists in iPad (such as UISplitviewcontroller). If that is the case, you can solve by weak linking UIKit framework in you project

Comment: You may also get this type of compilation error if you have forgotten to include a Framework, such as Foundation/Foundation.h or CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For this type of error, this is what I typically see:

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture armv6:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MyCustomController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SomeOtherController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv6
```

Almost every time I see this error it is caused by hidden/invisible characters in the import statement in `SomeOtherController.h` or `SomeOtherController.m`. So, look at both your .h and .m file, find the line that looks like this:

```
#import "MyCustomController.h"
```

Delete this line and retype it (do not copy/paste it -- you'll just repaste the offending hidden character).

Comment: I've also came across this exact issue when I wasn't including some files in the specific build target.

Comment: @raidfive: THANK YOU!! I was having this same issue, and it was caused because for some reason Xcode in it's infinite wisdom decided not to place the .m files for a couple classes into the Compile Sources section of my target. Added them manually and it compiled fine.

Comment: @Answerbot Thanks for your this solution but its not working for me . I got error like this Undefined symbols for architecture armv6:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CLLocationManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MyCLController.o .. Need to solve it urgent .. I have also remove that heder file #import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h> ..

Comment: @Vivek2012: I guess you probably need to add the CoreLocation Framework to your project

Answer (score 12):

**Here's how I got this problem:**

I added a `.h`, `.m` and NIB from another project by dragging them onto my project navigator. Xcode didn't add them to the Build Phases properly.

**My solution for this problem:**

[image]

- Click on the Project icon
- Go to the Target in the navigator menu
- Click on the "Build Phases" tab
- Add the `.m` file to "Compile Sources" (either drag it across, or use the + button)
- Add the `.xib` or Storyboard file to "Copy bundle resources"
- Clean and build

Answer (score 8):

Click on your Project name in the navigation window, choose the target you're building against, go to build phases, make sure the one Xcode's telling you that's missing is in there.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in Xcode5 for iOS7 with the TestFlight SDK. My issue was that the 'Build Active Architecture Only' was set to Debug only.

You can find the setting under **'YourProject'->'Build Settings'->'Architectures'** Set the 'Release' option to 'Yes'.

This solved my problem - I hope it helps you, too! :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was doing this in a viewcontroller.m

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
```

Without doing Link Binary With Libraries with MediaPlayer.framework. After adding it, it compiled fine

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and I have just solved it. 
It was a simple typo in the function name (forgot one letter) that caused the problem in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Xcode5 for iOS7 with the TestFlight SDK. My issue was that the 'Build Active Architecture Only' was set to Debug only.

You can find the setting under 'YourProject'->'Build Settings'->'Architectures' Set the 'Debug ' option to 'architecure arm7 arms7s'.

This solved my problem - I hope it helps you, too! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue popping-up all suddenly - more specifically, I was getting `Undefined symbols for architecture armv6: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CLLocationManager", referenced from: objc-class-ref in MyCLController.o`

Note that I had CoreLocation.framework listed in my frameworks (in xcode' Project left nav, under the Frameworks folder); and had previously geolocation working just fine.

I got rid of the issue by re-installing CoreLocation.framework.

If you're not sure how to do that in xcode:
* click on your project in xcode left nav bar 
* Go in the General tab of your project settings 
* Navigate down - you'll see the list of frameworks installed under `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` 
* Click on the `+` icon to add the CoreLocation.framework