# Undefined symbols for architecture armv6

Tags: iphone, ios, armv6

My app compiles fine on the iPhone simulator running iOS 5.0, but it fails on my older physical iPod touch running iOS 4.2.1.

I'm getting the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv6:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TestFlight", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv6
```

I've looked at other questions about this:
[Undefined symbols for architecture armv6, Updating to iOS 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403575/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv6-updating-to-ios-4-3)

But they're solutions do not work. Indeed, TestFlight.h was not in Compile sources, but dragging it to Compile Sources did not change the error message. (There is no TestFlight.m; I have libTestFlight.a in "Link Binary with Libraries"

Similarly, deleting and retyping `#import "TestFlight.h"` in AppDelegate.m did not change anything.

What else could be causing this compile error on my iPod?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined symbols for architecture armv6, Updating to iOS 4.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403575/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv6-updating-to-ios-4-3)

Answer (score 1):

First, a .h file is not a source file, so remove it from "Compile Sources" again.

About the error - you are probably using a version of the TestFlight SDK that does not support armv6 - they re-enabled this architecture in a recent version. Update to the newest version of the SDK and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Click on your project, select

> Target

and then goto

> Build Phases

In

> Compile Sources

added AppDelegate.m, it might not be connected, compiler is unable to find the file.
Also see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403575/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv6-updating-to-ios-4-3)